# FastAPI responds with required field is missing

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

I'm following a simple tutorial from the FastAPI docs. I was already using SQLAlchemy in this project just added the fastapi dependency and trying to run it, here's my code:

```
import re
import json
import copy
import traceback
import urllib.parse
from models import *
from mangum import Mangum
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from collections import defaultdict
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Request, Response

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def db_session_middleware(request, call_next):
    response = Response("Internal server error", status_code=500)
    try:
        engine = create_engine(
            "some db"
        )
        base.metadata.create_all(engine)
        request.state.db = Session(engine)
        response = await call_next(request)
    finally:
        request.state.db.close()
    return response


def get_db(request):
    return request.state.db


@app.get("/")
def get_root():
    return {"Status": "OK"}


@app.get("/products/{sku}")
def get_product(sku, db=Depends(get_db)):
    pass


@app.get("/products", status_code=200)
def get_products(page: int = 1, page_size: int = 50, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    try:
        result, sku_list = [], []
        for row in (
            db.query(Product, Image)
            .filter(Product.sku == Image.sku)
            .limit(page_size)
            .offset(page * page_size)
        ):
            if row[0].sku not in sku_list:
                result.append(
                    {
                        "sku": row[0].sku,
                        "brand": row[0].brand,
                        "image": row[1].image_url,
                        "title": row[0].product_title,
                        "price": row[0].original_price,
                        "reviewCount": row[0].total_reviews,
                        "rating": row[0].overall_rating,
                    }
                )
                sku_list.append(row[0].sku)

        print(f"Result: {result}")
        return {"body": {"message": "Success", "result": result}, "statusCode": 200}
    except Exception as err:
        print(traceback.format_exc(err))
        return {
            "body": {"message": "Failure", "result": traceback.format_exc(err)},
            "statusCode": 500,
        }
```

When I hit the products endpoint using this url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products?page=1&page_size=100
```

I'm getting this response:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["query","request"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

I'm not sure what it means by `query` and `request` missing in the response. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

declare `request` as argument.
not  `async def endp(request, ...)`, but `async def endp(request: Request, ...)`

import Request from fastapi
`from fastapi import Request`

Comment: I've addded it `def get_products(request: Request, page: int = 1, page_size: int = 50, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):` but I'm still getting same response

Comment: example from official site:
```# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.post("/users/", response_model=schemas.User)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):```

try changing get_db part

Comment: It's not related to session, but thanks though

Answer (score 0):

To [use the `Request` object](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/), you need to declare the parameter (e.g., `request`) with the type being the `Request`, and hence, FastAPI will know to pass the `Request` in that parameter; otherwise, it is considered as query parameter—hence, the error:

```
["query","request"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"
```

### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

app = FastAPI()

def get_db(request: Request):
    return request.state.db
    
@app.get("/products", status_code=200)
def get_products(page: int = 1, page_size: int = 50, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    pass
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had to add type to `get_db` function parameter:

```
def get_db(request: Request):
 ...
```